# iOS11 crashes on AVPlayerItemTrack.assetTrack.mediaType (Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x0)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, ios11

I am key-value observing the tracks property from an AVPlayerItem like so:

```
override func observeValue(forKeyPath keyPath: String?, of object: Any?, change: [NSKeyValueChangeKey : Any]?, context: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?) {
    if context == &PlayerItemObserverContext {
        [... more code...]
        } else if keyPath == #keyPath(AVPlayerItem.tracks) {
            if let playerItem = self.playerItem {
                for track in playerItem.tracks where track.assetTrack.mediaType == AVMediaType.video {
                    // Do something with the track
                    break
                }
            }
        } [... more code...]
```

But when skipping fast forward my app crashes here

```
for track in playerItem.tracks where track.assetTrack.mediaType == AVMediaType.video {
```

The XCode 9 debugger says `Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x0`

I can clearly see that track.assetTrack is nil!

```
(lldb) po track.assetTrack
 <uninitialized>
(lldb) po track
<AVPlayerItemTrack: 0x1c80083b0, assetTrack = (null)>
```

This is not supposed to happen, since the type of `assetTrack` on `AVPlayerItemTrack` is `var assetTrack: AVAssetTrack { get }`. But clearly this is not true.

(All handling of video is done on the main thread)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The myth here is that when programming Swift (4 in this case) you are in a safe environment. What I have learned the hard way is that the language might be safe, but the runtime is not.

The (hopefully temporary) fix is to do the following:

```
for track in playerItem.tracks where track.assetTrack != nil && track.assetTrack.mediaType == AVMediaType.video {
```

Even the compiler thinks this is stupid, since XCode complains:

```
Comparing non-optional value of type 'AVAssetTrack' to nil always returns true
```

But it does the trick, and the app doesn't crash anymore!

The code works **without** the fix on iOS10 and previous versions, but iOS11 seems to have a serious regression in this area.

Comment: Did you file a radar? This is clearly a bug on Apple's side. I would bet that it's written in objective-c and either the exposed swift definition is wrong or the obj-c code is treating it like an optional, since it doesn't have the safety that Swift does. 

What's weird is that I didn't see this crash until i converted to Swift 4. Swift 3 + iOS 11 wasn't crashing.

Comment: I did not file a radar.